# How to create a input field that will process a query and return that query

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

How to create a input field that will process a query and return that query?

What I am trying to accomplish is:

Submit button will take the input and push it to the $mapname
the $mapname will be the substitute for the missing argument in the query (`mapname`)

once the substitute is in place

The query with the missing arguement is defined in $mapquery

$mapstmt is to prepare the database connection and $mapquery

once the button is set as POST it will run the map stmt and return the query

and list the results.

My problem is this is not working so any help will be appreciated.

```
elseif ($Page == "records")
    {
    echo "Please enter the map you wish to view records for!<br /><br />";
    echo "<br /> Example: surf_mesa";
    echo "<form method=\"POST\">";
    echo "<input value=\"\" type=\"text\" name=\"mapname\" />";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">";
    echo "<br /><br /><a href=\"$Home\">Go back</a>";

    $mapname = $_POST['mapname'];
    // echo $mapname;
    if(isset($_POST['sumbit']))
    {
        $mapquery = "SELECT * FROM `ck_playertimes` WHERE `mapname` = ?";

        $mapstmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $mapquery);

        if ($mapstmt) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($mapstmt, "s", $mapname);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($mapstmt);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($mapstmt)) {
            echo [$mapstmt];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo [$mapstmt]` - what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @PedroLobito echo [$mapstmt] I was trying to see if I could print out the results but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score -1):

This is not the proper way:

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($mapstmt)) {
        echo [$mapstmt];
        }
```

You need to write

```
 while ($rs = mysqli_stmt_fetch($mapstmt)) {
            print_r($rs);
            }
```

Comment: I have tried [code] while ($querydata = mysqli_stmt_fetch($mapstmt)) {
       print_r($querydata); [/code] but that did not work.

Comment: what do you mean by 'did not work'. it should print the result of the query.If it is blank, then your query does not return anything. For that case echo the query in browser & run the query directly in mysql/phpmyadmin/mysql workbench